# MethodHandle.Lookup for classes loaded outside of default ClassLoader

Tags: java

I'm using the stuff of java.lang.invoke to create lambdas out of methods obtained by reflection.
When the method is called frequently, it improves performances.

It works quite well, until I discovered that it no longer works when the method comes from a class loaded by a ClassLoader different than the default one.

What have I missed ?
What do I need to change in order to make it work ?

IN case there is an importance, I'm on Java 17.

First of all, the class I'm going to load externally:

```
public class TestFunc {
  public static String testFunc (String str) {
    return str.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

Then, the main example code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.lang.invoke.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestLambda {

  public static <I> I createLambda (Object obj, Executable method, Class<I> interfaceClass, Class<?> returnType, String name, Class<?>... mArgs) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    try {
      method.setAccessible(true);
      boolean isConstructor = method instanceof Constructor, isStatic = isConstructor || Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers()), isBound = obj!=null&&!isStatic;
      var cls = method.getDeclaringClass();
      var pt = method.getParameterTypes();
      var rt = isConstructor? cls : ((Method)method) .getReturnType();
      var lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
      if (Modifier.isPrivate(method.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isProtected(method.getModifiers())) lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(cls, lookup);
      var mh = isConstructor? lookup.unreflectConstructor((Constructor)method) : lookup.unreflect((Method)method);
      var  interfaceMT = isBound? MethodType.methodType(interfaceClass, cls) : MethodType.methodType(interfaceClass);
      var implementationMT = MethodType.methodType(returnType, mArgs);
      var calledMT = isStatic || isBound? MethodType.methodType(rt, pt) : MethodType.methodType(rt, cls, pt);
      var callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, name, interfaceMT, implementationMT, mh, calledMT);
      return (I) (isBound?
        callSite.getTarget() .invoke(obj) :
        callSite.getTarget() .invoke() );
    } catch (Throwable t) { 
      throw new ReflectiveOperationException(t);
    }
  }
  
  public static <T,R> Function<T,R> createFunction (Object obj, Executable method, Class<T> argType, Class<R> returnType) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    return (Function<T,R>) createLambda(obj, method, Function.class, Object.class, "apply", Object.class);
  }
  
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Throwable {
    // Example usage with a trivial case where it works well
    Method toUpperCaseMethod = String.class.getMethod("toUpperCase");
    Function<String, String> toUpperCaseFunction = createFunction(null, toUpperCaseMethod, String.class, String.class);
    System.out.println(toUpperCaseFunction.apply("Hello, world!"));
    
    // Example 2 to show that calling the external method via standars reflection API works as well
    ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader( new URL[]{ new File("test.jar").toURL() }, TestLambda.class.getClassLoader());
    Class theClass = classLoader.loadClass("TestFunc");
    Method method = theClass.getMethod("testFunc", String.class);
    System.out.println(method.invoke(null, "This is working"));
    
    // Example 3 where it doesn't work
    Function<String,String> func = createFunction(null, method, String.class, String.class);
    System.out.println(func.apply("This doesn't work"));
  }

}
```

Result :

```
HELLO, WORLD!
THIS IS WORKING
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestFunc
    at TestLambda.main(TestLambda.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestFunc
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main$MemoryClassLoader.loadClass(Main.java:600)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at TestLambda.main(TestLambda.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:419)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:192)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. It works when using MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance.

Performance wise, I presume it's one order slower than the LambdaMetafactory, because it then pass via JDK Proxy.

I still don't understand why it doesn't work with LambdaMetafactory, and what it changes when it's done via a proxy.
Does someone has any idea ? Feel free to post the explanation in another answer if you have it.

The code becomes as follows:

```
public static <I> I createLambda (Object obj, Executable method, Class<I> interfaceClass, Class<?> returnType, String name, Class<?>... mArgs) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
  try {
    method.setAccessible(true);
    boolean isConstructor = method instanceof Constructor, isStatic = isConstructor || Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers()), isBound = obj!=null&&!isStatic;
    var cls = method.getDeclaringClass();
    var targetClassLoader = cls.getClassLoader();
    var pt = method.getParameterTypes();
    var rt = isConstructor? cls : ((Method)method) .getReturnType();
    var lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    if (Modifier.isPrivate(method.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isProtected(method.getModifiers())) lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(cls, lookup);
    var mh = isConstructor? lookup.unreflectConstructor((Constructor)method) : lookup.unreflect((Method)method);
    if (targetClassLoader!=null && targetClassLoader!=TestLambda.class.getClassLoader()) {
      return (I) MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(interfaceClass, mh);
    }
    else {
      var  interfaceMT = isBound? MethodType.methodType(interfaceClass, cls) : MethodType.methodType(interfaceClass);
      var implementationMT = MethodType.methodType(returnType, mArgs);
      var calledMT = isStatic || isBound? MethodType.methodType(rt, pt) : MethodType.methodType(rt, cls, pt);
              var callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, name, interfaceMT, implementationMT, mh, calledMT);
              return (I) (isBound?
                callSite.getTarget() .invoke(obj) :
        callSite.getTarget() .invoke() );
      }
  } catch (Throwable t) { 
    throw t instanceof ReflectiveOperationException r? r : new ReflectiveOperationException(t);
  }
}
```